# Global axis align using edge constraint (vertex slide) and vertex snap

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

when I use snap on vertex while using vertex slide, it's like if Blender uses the Normal transform Orientation even if I have selected the Global one, moving the vertex in an unwanted position.

I made a quick video of example, at the end I move freely the vertex to the wanted position just so you can better see what I mean: https://imgur.com/CJCnZ9o

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!
White